# How to move focus to next input field in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my codepen link https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/LYxOoWO

I have otp field, When all 4 fields, if i fill and press backspace/delete button. then only it is moving back and deleting enterd numbers.

But issue with below code is, When i enter single digit in otp field and press backspace/delete button,
it's not moving backwards.(staying in same input field)

```html
// Shift focus to next input field if max length reached
        if (value.length >= maxlength) {          
          if (typeof this.activationKeyFields[index + 1] == 'undefined') {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
          }
          this.$refs[`input-${parseInt(index + 1)}`][0].focus();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      else{
          if (typeof this.activationKeyFields[index - 1] == 'undefined') {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
        this.$refs[`input-${parseInt(index - 1)}`][0].focus();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      },
```

Comment: It is because you are bound to the input event. When you are hitting the backspace key to go backward it is doing nothing because the length of the field is not changing. If you were to manually move your cursor back to a filled box and hit backspace it would work.. To get this to work how you want you should listen to the `@keyup` event

Comment: @SuitBoyApps, I want it as, After entering any single digit number in out of 4 input fields, and pressing the backspace button, In that case also i should able  to  delete by using backspace button.

Not like manually moving cursor and hitting backspace.

Comment: read my comment again. I give you the solution while explaining why @input is not the right solution for what you are attempting to accomplish.